# How to set SynchronousInitialization and SynchronousUpdating on DynamicGeoGraphics?

Tags: dynamic, geography

`DynamicGeoGraphics` has its underlying `SynchronousInitialization` and `SynchronousUpdating` options set to `True` judging from the timeout it experiences when loading a large amount of geographic polygons.  However, these options are not currently available on this function (experimental in 11.0.1). Is there a method to set these options on this function?

For example, download the "Probabilistic Storm Surge" file from the National Hurricane Centre GIS site ([here](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/)). Then,

```
geo = "Geometry" /. Import[filenameSurge, {"SHP", "Data"}];
```

returns the storm surge geometry.  There are about 119 items in the current file.

```
DynamicGeoGraphics[geo]
```

> ```
> $Aborted
> ```

`DynamicGeoGraphics` times out as would a `DynamicModule` with a long initialization and `SynchronousInitialization -> True` (the default). However a static `GeoGraphics` will complete with a time.

```
GeoGraphics[geo]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any behind the scenes hacks to get at these options and set them to `False`.

Comment: I want to test this out, but which of the files [here](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gis/archive_psurge.php) (i.e. which year and which tropical cyclone) did you use?

Comment: @J.M. I used Matthew in 2016.